# Issue with GCP GKE HPA cannot read metric value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We were testing for scaling using CPU utilization on GKE GCP but ran into this error of " HPA cannot read metric value" for cpu utilization. I am not able to find the solution. Earlier the setup was working with the exact same installation steps but now giving this error. In the events the error is

```
unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)   FailedGetResourceMetric 
    
failed to compute desired number of replicas based on listed metrics for Deployment/testscale/testscale: failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)   FailedComputeMetricsReplicas
```

I tried by placing resource requests in yaml but doesnt work. Also tried the following to get some info on metric server but shows server not available. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep metrics-server
kube-system   metrics-server-v0.3.6-856b7cfdd5-6ngjt                      0/2     Pending   0          5h40m
kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods"
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

Comment: kubectl top pods
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
kubectl top pods
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)```

Comment: You won't get metrics, as metrics-server pod was not deployed. What GKE version are you using? Please provide output of `kubectl describe po metrics-server-v0.3.6-856b7cfdd5-6ngjt  -n kube-system` to check why pod is still in `Pending` state IT might be due to lack of resources, taints, policy, etc.   How much resources did you assign to this cluster (RAM and CPU). How many nodes have your cluster?

Comment: when i tried redeploying its in running state but still hpa metric error "kube-system   metrics-server-v0.3.6-64655c969-88tlc                       2/2     Running   0          3h19m"

Comment: This api call is also working ```kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/scaletest1/pods"```, also issue is coming in some regions and other regions with same deployment its working fine

Comment: This issue is affecting only in some regions and not all with the same workload being used

Comment: Please provide all steps to reproduce this issue (How did you create cluster, what features was enabled, all commands you have used). Also provide `kubectl describe` command as I mentioned before. Information in Events might be helpful. Also output of `kubectl logs <podname> -n kube-system` would help here.

Comment: This issue can occur when the node pool autoscaler (IG autoscaler) adds a node. The error goes away after a while. I figure the HorizontalPodAutoscaler is activating before the node is fully online. I don't know if that's what's happening here, but I'm mentioning this in case others show up here wondering about the problem.